# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Rails 4, deployed, need help reading log file & debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed Rails 4 apps to Heroku several times just fine, but I'm still somewhat a noob at understanding full stack web development.  I tried deploying an app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk (both with zip files on the User Interface and through Git: the project 'uploaded' fine both ways), but clicking on my default-environment.elasticbeanstalk.com still leads me to the default elastic beanstalk "Congratulations" page rather than my app.

I pulled up the log file for my last attempted deploy and am posting the failures/errors below. I have no idea what any of this really means or how to really change my Rails files to accomodate any of it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been looking around the web and there's not too much out there regarding this!

/var/log/eb-tools.log
https://gist.github.com/geeko505/d724322b628da8766754

/var/log/cfn-init.log
https://gist.github.com/geeko505/f89cca57947c3ac920cd

At the very bottom:

```
Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
sh: git: command not found
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
"/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-    d67faab23e9b7asddefbc8efb34a2344a851e9f78b2ca"
--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /var/app/ondeck has failed.

2014-06-16 01:33:22,778 [ERROR] (28326 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-33] [root     directoryHooksExecutor error] Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed with returncode 11
```

don't worry, i replaced the secret keys with gibberish

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should install git on your beanstalk environment using ebextensions.
Try creating a file with path `.ebextensions/00-install-git.config` in your app source directory before deploying to beanstalk.

```
packages:
    yum:
        git: []
```

Make sure to commit this file before deployment in case you are using eb/git for deploying to beanstalk.